# What products should i add on an azure price scenario, to deploy a simple virtual machine with disk space to serve as database?

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

Currently we are hosting a .net core app running mongodb as a database on location in our phisical servers, what services would i need to get it running in azure?

Is a virtual machine, with added hard disk space enough?

Why are there dedicated products on marketpalce for example for "sql servers" if you can just install them in the virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for a PaaS model because it is cheapest and you have alot of features easy to use out of the box just with a few clicks.
You delegate responsibilities to Microsoft to monitor your resources, maintenance, OS, networking, Security and Hardware.

1. I would recommend migrate your On-Prem mongoDB to a CosmosDB with a mongoDB connector so your app can do the same stuff doing currently.
2. You should host your app/web app inside a Web App Service with a production tier.
3. Also you will need some kind of infrastructure topology like Vnets, NSG or private links and endpoints if you want to isolate public endpoints and make your application private PaaS (also upgrade your app service to an isolation tier instead of production).
4. You can take a look at pricing calculator to check if it is worth for you or not: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

If you want an IaaS approach i would recommend to use a D+ Series Virtual Machine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!, do you know why this question was tagged as "opinion based"? what's opinion based in a quesiton like this? i don't understand

Comment: no idea sorry, maybe need more detailed information so the answer can be more accurate. What i did was just a recommendation.

Comment: I'ts hard to give details on a topic you dont know and the reason someone might post here in the first place, but your answer is good for me, that was a good example on what i needed, thank you